# Button click event from page loaded in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog

I'm trying to load a "cancel" page in a jQuery dialog.

The jQuery dialog has confirmation buttons "YES" and "NO". If I click the "YES" button, it should fire button `click` event from `cancel.aspx` page loaded in jQuery dialog.

How can I call click event from loaded page?

**Modify.aspx**

```html
<html>
    <div id="dialogCancel" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#dialogCancel").load('Cancel.aspx').dialog({
            open: function() {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            },
            width: '300',
            height: '200',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: 'fade',
                duration: 1500
            },

            buttons: {
                'Yes': function() {
                    //if YES fire button click event from cancel page loaded in jquery dialog.
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                    'No': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

**Cancel.aspx**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cancel.aspx.cs" %>
<html>

    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="Scripts/Jquery/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="red">
        <form id="Cancel" runat="server">
            <div id="div1">
                <center>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Yes" Height="28px" Visible="False" onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
                </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to modify the markup. Set btnCancel `Visible="true"`. `Visible="false"` will stop this control from rendering. You want the button to be invisible, lets do this in css : `style="display:none"`. Here's my markup for Cancel.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cancel.aspx.cs" %>

<html>

    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="Scripts/Jquery/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="red">
        <form id="Cancel" runat="server">
            <div id="div1">
                <center>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Yes" Height="28px" Visible="true" onclick="btnCancel_Click" style="display:none;"/>
                </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now in the script we need to make some changes. I have included jquery and jquery ui. We need to trigger click event of the cancel button. but after that we need to make sure that we are not reloading the page in out test. I have commented the line for now. Here's the markup of Modify.aspx with jquery:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <div id="dialogCancel" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#dialogCancel").load('Cancel.aspx').dialog({
            open: function () {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            },
            width: '300',
            height: '200',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: 'fade',
                duration: 1500
            },

            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () {
                    //if YES fire button click event from cancel page loaded in jquery dialog.
                    $("#btnCancel").trigger("click");
                    //location.reload(true);//Uncomment this line once you are done with testing
                },
                'No': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You afzalulh, It's awesome ! btncancel click event works fine.